# Gaussian Grassmann integral with complex/bosonic source term

Tags: path-integral, fermions, complex-numbers, grassmann-numbers

I'm interested in solving the following multi-dimensional integral

$$
\int d \theta d \bar{\theta} e^{-\bar{\theta}M \theta +\Lambda \theta + \bar{\theta} J }
$$

where $\theta$ is a $N$-dimensional vector of **odd** Grassmann numbers while $M,\Lambda,J$ are composed of **even** Grassmann numbers (different from $\theta$). I have looked everywhere but I can only find situations where $\Lambda,J$ are also odd Grassmann variables. In that case, we can do a simple shift of variables such that the new variables also have a well-defined odd-parity. This is not the case for even $\Lambda,J$.

A simpler case of this integral is that of a single Grassmann number and $M,\Lambda,J$ being complex matrices. I've tried to solve by expanding the exponential and ignoring the higher-order terms $\mathcal{O}(\bar{\theta}\theta\bar{\theta}\theta)$

$$
\int d \theta d \bar{\theta} e^{-\bar{\theta}  M \theta +\Lambda \theta + \bar{\theta} J }=\int d \theta d \bar{\theta} (1-\bar{\theta } M \theta +\Lambda \theta + \bar{\theta} J +\frac{1}{2} (\Lambda \theta \bar{\theta} J + \bar{\theta} J \Lambda \theta))=\int d \theta d \bar{\theta} (-M \bar{\theta }\theta +\frac{\Lambda J}{2} (\theta \bar{\theta} + \bar{\theta} \theta)).
$$

but since $\theta$ are even numbers we have $(\theta \bar{\theta} + \bar{\theta} \theta)=0$ and the final result does not depend on $J,\Lambda$ which should be wrong. Could you help me understand what is wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

OP's manipulations are correct for $N=1$ if we define the exponential function via its Taylor series, cf. Ref. 1. Note that the argument of the exponential function is usually Grassmann-even in physical theories.

References:

1. Bryce DeWitt, *Supermanifolds,* Cambridge Univ. Press, 1992; eq. (1.1.6).

Comment: 1. Does it mean that the integral does not depend on $\Lambda,J$? 2. This type of integral can emerge when we consider two fermionic systems coupled with a Hamiltonian of the type $H=c^{\dagger}c(a^\dagger+a).$ If we wish to trace out the $a$ degrees of freedom, we must solve the above integral.

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. A Grassmann-odd Hamiltonian is unusual.

Comment: Great thanks for the reference but I still cannot understand how come it does not depend, it's suspicious to have such different behavior between bosons and fermions. Also, the formula is not compatible with Eq.3.8 of the Introduction to Superanalysis by Berezin. As far as I understood, it says we can simply do the shift in variables $\theta \rightarrow \theta - J $,$\bar{\theta} \rightarrow {\theta} - J $ and we should compute the superdeterminant which, in this case, gives 1. Then we can expand the exponential to obtain $e^{JM^{-1}\Lambda}$

Comment: Berezin is in eq. (3.8) on p. 13 only considering coordinates of definite Grassmann parity, and Grassmann parity preserving change of coordinates. The shift $\theta \rightarrow \theta - J$ violates this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have constructed a correct answer that is independent of the parity of the shift variable but the result does not agree with the 1-dimensional case discussed in the question.

$$ \int d\theta d\bar{\theta}e^{-\bar{\theta}M\theta+\Lambda\bar{\theta}+\theta J} \\=\int d\theta d\bar{\theta}e^{-\tilde{\bar{\theta}}M\tilde{\theta}+\Lambda M^{-1}J}
 \\=\int d\theta d\bar{\theta}\sum_{n}\frac{\left(\Lambda M^{-1}J-\tilde{\bar{\theta}}M\tilde{\theta}\right)^{n}}{n!}
 \\=\int d\theta d\bar{\theta}\sum_{n}\frac{\text{Permutations}\left\{ \Lambda M^{-1}J,-\tilde{\bar{\theta}}M\tilde{\theta}\right\} }{n!}$$

Where we redefined the variables
$$\tilde{\theta}=\theta-M^{-1}J\qquad\text{and}\qquad\tilde{\bar{\theta}}=\bar{\theta}-\Lambda M^{-1}.$$
By Permutations$\{A,B\}$ I mean all the terms $AAA...,BAA...,ABA...,...BBB$ without exchanging any terms since $\tilde{\theta}$ does not have a well defined parity and we want to avoid it. Next we recall that only the highest order terms in $\theta,\bar{\theta}$ can remain and those correspond to replacing $\tilde{\theta}\rightarrow \theta$. But since $\Lambda M^{-1}J$ and $\bar{\theta}M\theta$ both have even parity, we can now apply binomial theorem to get:

$$ \int d\theta d\bar{\theta}\sum_{n}\frac{\text{Permutations}\left\{ \Lambda M^{-1}J,-\bar{\theta}M\theta\right\} }{n!}+\text{lower order terms in $\theta$}
 \\=\int d\theta d\bar{\theta}\sum_{n=0}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{c}
n\\
k
\end{array}\right)\frac{\left(\Lambda M^{-1}J\right)^{n-k}\left(-\bar{\theta}M\theta\right)^{k}}{n!}
 \\=\int d\theta d\bar{\theta}\sum_{n=d}\left(\begin{array}{c}
n\\
d
\end{array}\right)\frac{\left(\Lambda M^{-1}J\right)^{n-d}\left(-\bar{\theta}M\theta\right)^{d}}{n!}
 \\=\frac{e^{\Lambda M^{-1}J}}{d!}\int d\theta d\bar{\theta}\left(-\bar{\theta}M\theta\right)^{d}
 \\=e^{\Lambda M^{-1}J}\det M$$

Comment: Comment to the answer (v3): The new variable $\tilde{\theta}=\theta-M^{-1}J$ is not of definite Grassmann parity, i.e. it is a mixture of Grassmann-odd and Grassmann-even parts.

Comment: Agreed but, if not mistaken, this proof never makes use of it?

Comment: Well, the [Berezin integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berezin_integral) is traditionally only defined for supervariables of definite Grassmann parity.